# New \gdef command does not give expected output

Tags: macros

The expected output of of the code below should be the simple phrase "Testing One two three", but instead, the output is just "One two three".

I have tried using `\xdef` to no avail, and I'm not sure what is wrong.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\gdef\@test{#1}}
\newcommand{\@test}[1]{Testing #1}
\makeatother

\test{One two three}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@test
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you expect `Testing` in the output?  executing `\test` defines `\@test` as a macro with no argument, over-writing the initial definition of `\@test` which takes an argument but is unused here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append to an existing macro rather tha over-write it, you could do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\g@addto@macro\@test{ #1}}
\newcommand{\@test}{Testing}
\makeatother

\test{One two three}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@test
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool.  I guess `\g@addto@macro` is defined deep down inside LaTeX??  Can it be generally used to add tokens to an existing `\def`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes well no deeper than other commands defined on the format, but yes.